# Output formatted json to a console.log

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have ajax which brings me back json,

What I want is to output everything inside 'routes' to a console.log but I don't know how to do that.

This is json output:

```
    {
  "geocoded_waypoints": [
    {
      "geocoder_status": "OK",
      "place_id": "ChIJuVnJ34G3e0gRW_oSYLOUxEc",
      "types": [
        "premise"
      ]
    },
    {
      "geocoder_status": "OK",
      "place_id": "ChIJ0afvWH-3e0gRehrvBJAsflw",
      "types": [
        "premise"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "routes": [
    {
      "bounds": {
        "northeast": {
          "lat": 53.541228,
          "lng": -2.1114936
        },
        "southwest": {
          "lat": 53.5406464,
          "lng": -2.1120657
        }
      },
      "copyrights": "Dane do Mapy ©2017 Google",
      "legs": [
        {
          "distance": {
            "text": "0,1 km",
            "value": 112
          },
          "duration": {
            "text": "1 min",
            "value": 27
          },
          "end_address": "Broseley House, 81 Union St, Oldham OL1 1PF, Wielka Brytania",
          "end_location": {
            "lat": 53.5406464,
            "lng": -2.1120657
          },
          "start_address": "Ashton Arms, Oldham, Wielka Brytania",
          "start_location": {
            "lat": 53.5411486,
            "lng": -2.1114936
          },
          "steps": [
            {
              "distance": {
                "text": "39 m",
                "value": 39
              },
              "duration": {
                "text": "1 min",
                "value": 7
              },
              "end_location": {
                "lat": 53.54116,
                "lng": -2.1119794
              },
              "html_instructions": "Kieruj się <b>Clegg St</b> na <b>północny zachód</b> w stronę <b>Ascroft St</b>",
              "polyline": {
                "points": "egxeIxk{KEBEDADAF?H@JJr@"
              },
              "start_location": {
                "lat": 53.5411486,
                "lng": -2.1114936
              },
              "travel_mode": "DRIVING"
            },
            {
              "distance": {
                "text": "52 m",
                "value": 52
              },
              "duration": {
                "text": "1 min",
                "value": 11
              },
              "end_location": {
                "lat": 53.5407078,
                "lng": -2.1117626
              },
              "html_instructions": "Skręć <b>w lewo</b> w <b>Harrison St</b>",
              "maneuver": "turn-left",
              "polyline": {
                "points": "ggxeIzn{KxAk@"
              },
              "start_location": {
                "lat": 53.54116,
                "lng": -2.1119794
              },
              "travel_mode": "DRIVING"
            },
            {
              "distance": {
                "text": "21 m",
                "value": 21
              },
              "duration": {
                "text": "1 min",
                "value": 9
              },
              "end_location": {
                "lat": 53.5406464,
                "lng": -2.1120657
              },
              "html_instructions": "Skręć <b>w prawo</b> w <b>Printer St</b>",
              "maneuver": "turn-right",
              "polyline": {
                "points": "mdxeInm{KJ|@"
              },
              "start_location": {
                "lat": 53.5407078,
                "lng": -2.1117626
              },
              "travel_mode": "DRIVING"
            }
          ],
          "traffic_speed_entry": [],
          "via_waypoint": []
        }
      ],
      "overview_polyline": {
        "points": "egxeIxk{KKHCL@TJr@xAk@J|@"
      },
      "summary": "Ascroft St i Harrison St",
      "warnings": [],
      "waypoint_order": []
    }
  ],
  "status": "OK"
}
```

How can I sort this json so I will only output everything inside routes?

Ajax:

```
  function getDirections(lat, lng, destinationLat, destinationLng) {
  $.ajax({
      url: '/google',
      type: 'post',
      data: { lat: lat, lng: lng, destinationLat: destinationLat, destinationLng: destinationLng },
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(data) { 
        console.log(data.routes);
      },
      error: function() { alert('boo!'); },
      headers: {
          'X-CSRF-Token': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
      }  
    });
  }
```

Controller:

```
function getGoogle() {
    $lat = Input::get('lat');
    $lng = Input::get('lng');
    $destinationLat = Input::get('destinationLat');
    $destinationLng = Input::get('destinationLng');
    $google = file_get_contents('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin='.$lat.','.$lng.'&destination='.$destinationLat.','.$destinationLng.'&key=AIzaSyAirYgs4Xnt9QabG9v56jsIcCNfNZazq50');
    return response()->json(['data' => $google]);
}
```

//edit

console.log(data);

```
Object {data: "{↵   "geocoded_waypoints" : [↵      {↵         "ge…t_order" : []↵      }↵   ],↵   "status" : "OK"↵}↵"}data: "{↵   "geocoded_waypoints" : [↵      {↵         "geocoder_status" : "OK",↵         "place_id" : "ChIJuVnJ34G3e0gRW_oSYLOUxEc",↵         "types" : [ "premise" ]↵      },↵      {↵         "geocoder_status" : "OK",↵         "place_id" : "ChIJ0afvWH-3e0gRehrvBJAsflw",↵         "types" : [ "premise" ]↵      }↵   ],↵   "routes" : [↵      {↵         "bounds" : {↵            "northeast" : {↵               "lat" : 53.541228,↵               "lng" : -2.1114828↵            },↵            "southwest" : {↵               "lat" : 53.5406464,↵               "lng" : -2.1120657↵            }↵         },↵         "copyrights" : "Map data ©2017 Google",↵         "legs" : [↵            {↵               "distance" : {↵                  "text" : "0.1 km",↵                  "value" : 114↵               },↵               "duration" : {↵                  "text" : "1 min",↵                  "value" : 27↵               },↵               "end_address" : "Broseley House, 81 Union St, Oldham OL1 1PF, UK",↵               "end_location" : {↵                  "lat" : 53.5406464,↵                  "lng" : -2.1120657↵               },↵               "start_address" : "Ashton Arms, Oldham, UK",↵               "start_location" : {↵                  "lat" : 53.5411291,↵                  "lng" : -2.1114828↵               },↵               "steps" : [↵                  {↵                     "distance" : {↵                        "text" : "41 m",↵                        "value" : 41↵                     },↵                     "duration" : {↵                        "text" : "1 min",↵                        "value" : 7↵                     },↵                     "end_location" : {↵                        "lat" : 53.54116,↵                        "lng" : -2.1119794↵                     },↵                     "html_instructions" : "Head \u003cb\u003enorthwest\u003c/b\u003e on \u003cb\u003eClegg St\u003c/b\u003e toward \u003cb\u003eAscroft St\u003c/b\u003e",↵                     "polyline" : {↵                        "points" : "agxeIvk{KIDEDADAF?H@JJr@"↵                     },↵                     "start_location" : {↵                        "lat" : 53.5411291,↵                        "lng" : -2.1114828↵                     },↵                     "travel_mode" : "DRIVING"↵                  },↵                  {↵                     "distance" : {↵                        "text" : "52 m",↵                        "value" : 52↵                     },↵                     "duration" : {↵                        "text" : "1 min",↵                        "value" : 11↵                     },↵                     "end_location" : {↵                        "lat" : 53.5407078,↵                        "lng" : -2.1117626↵                     },↵                     "html_instructions" : "Turn \u003cb\u003eleft\u003c/b\u003e onto \u003cb\u003eHarrison St\u003c/b\u003e",↵                     "maneuver" : "turn-left",↵                     "polyline" : {↵                        "points" : "ggxeIzn{KxAk@"↵                     },↵                     "start_location" : {↵                        "lat" : 53.54116,↵                        "lng" : -2.1119794↵                     },↵                     "travel_mode" : "DRIVING"↵                  },↵                  {↵                     "distance" : {↵                        "text" : "21 m",↵                        "value" : 21↵                     },↵                     "duration" : {↵                        "text" : "1 min",↵                        "value" : 9↵                     },↵                     "end_location" : {↵                        "lat" : 53.5406464,↵                        "lng" : -2.1120657↵                     },↵                     "html_instructions" : "Turn \u003cb\u003eright\u003c/b\u003e onto \u003cb\u003ePrinter St\u003c/b\u003e",↵                     "maneuver" : "turn-right",↵                     "polyline" : {↵                        "points" : "mdxeInm{KJ|@"↵                     },↵                     "start_location" : {↵                        "lat" : 53.5407078,↵                        "lng" : -2.1117626↵                     },↵                     "travel_mode" : "DRIVING"↵                  }↵               ],↵               "traffic_speed_entry" : [],↵               "via_waypoint" : []↵            }↵         ],↵         "overview_polyline" : {↵            "points" : "agxeIvk{KOJCL@TJr@xAk@J|@"↵         },↵         "summary" : "Ascroft St and Harrison St",↵         "warnings" : [],↵         "waypoint_order" : []↵      }↵   ],↵   "status" : "OK"↵}↵"__proto__: Objectconstructor: function Object()hasOwnProperty: function hasOwnProperty()isPrototypeOf: function isPrototypeOf()propertyIsEnumerable: function propertyIsEnumerable()toLocaleString: function toLocaleString()toString: function toString()valueOf: function valueOf()__defineGetter__: function __defineGetter__()__defineSetter__: function __defineSetter__()__lookupGetter__: function __lookupGetter__()__lookupSetter__: function __lookupSetter__()get __proto__: function __proto__()set __proto__: function __proto__()
```

Comment: What you want to display?

Comment: `console.log(obj.routes)`...?

Comment: console.log(data.routes) gives me undefined. @PankajMakwana I want to output all the details inside routes, of course without the titles, the actual values so for example routes.duration.(output text) etc

Comment: Can you please show AJAX code

Comment: The given JSON is invalid.

Comment: @Teemu this is what google gives me... try it: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=53.541156099999995,-2.1114554&destination=53.54027,-2.1121799999999666

Comment: Then it is not JSON, you've a JS object.

Comment: @PankajMakwana I have updated code to include ajax + controller

Comment: What you want to display and where you want to display?

Comment: distance.text and duration.text I wantto display it in bootstrap modal that would be ideal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check below thing it may help you. In JSON response you are passing `data` key with response so on ajax part you have to use `data.data.routes` to get proper output.

```
function getGoogle() {
    $lat = Input::get('lat');
    $lng = Input::get('lng');
    $destinationLat = Input::get('destinationLat');
    $destinationLng = Input::get('destinationLng');
    $google = file_get_contents('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=' . $lat . ',' . $lng . '&destination=' . $destinationLat . ',' . $destinationLng . '&key=AIzaSyAirYgs4Xnt9QabG9v56jsIcCNfNZazq50');
    return response()->json(['data' => json_decode($google)]);
 // Google's response by default is in JSON, so I've converted to array `json_decode($google)`.
}
```

```js
//Here is the json response you get from ajax success.
var json = {
  "geocoded_waypoints": [
    {
      "geocoder_status": "OK",
      "place_id": "ChIJuVnJ34G3e0gRW_oSYLOUxEc",
      "types": [
        "premise"
      ]
    },
    {
      "geocoder_status": "OK",
      "place_id": "ChIJ0afvWH-3e0gRehrvBJAsflw",
      "types": [
        "premise"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "routes": [
    {
      "bounds": {
        "northeast": {
          "lat": 53.541228,
          "lng": -2.1114936
        },
        "southwest": {
          "lat": 53.5406464,
          "lng": -2.1120657
        }
      },
      "copyrights": "Dane do Mapy ©2017 Google",
      "legs": [
        {
          "distance": {
            "text": "0,1 km",
            "value": 112
          },
          "duration": {
            "text": "1 min",
            "value": 27
          },
          "end_address": "Broseley House, 81 Union St, Oldham OL1 1PF, Wielka Brytania",
          "end_location": {
            "lat": 53.5406464,
            "lng": -2.1120657
          },
          "start_address": "Ashton Arms, Oldham, Wielka Brytania",
          "start_location": {
            "lat": 53.5411486,
            "lng": -2.1114936
          },
          "steps": [
            {
              "distance": {
                "text": "39 m",
                "value": 39
              },
              "duration": {
                "text": "1 min",
                "value": 7
              },
              "end_location": {
                "lat": 53.54116,
                "lng": -2.1119794
              },
              "html_instructions": "Kieruj się <b>Clegg St</b> na <b>północny zachód</b> w stronę <b>Ascroft St</b>",
              "polyline": {
                "points": "egxeIxk{KEBEDADAF?H@JJr@"
              },
              "start_location": {
                "lat": 53.5411486,
                "lng": -2.1114936
              },
              "travel_mode": "DRIVING"
            },
            {
              "distance": {
                "text": "52 m",
                "value": 52
              },
              "duration": {
                "text": "1 min",
                "value": 11
              },
              "end_location": {
                "lat": 53.5407078,
                "lng": -2.1117626
              },
              "html_instructions": "Skręć <b>w lewo</b> w <b>Harrison St</b>",
              "maneuver": "turn-left",
              "polyline": {
                "points": "ggxeIzn{KxAk@"
              },
              "start_location": {
                "lat": 53.54116,
                "lng": -2.1119794
              },
              "travel_mode": "DRIVING"
            },
            {
              "distance": {
                "text": "21 m",
                "value": 21
              },
              "duration": {
                "text": "1 min",
                "value": 9
              },
              "end_location": {
                "lat": 53.5406464,
                "lng": -2.1120657
              },
              "html_instructions": "Skręć <b>w prawo</b> w <b>Printer St</b>",
              "maneuver": "turn-right",
              "polyline": {
                "points": "mdxeInm{KJ|@"
              },
              "start_location": {
                "lat": 53.5407078,
                "lng": -2.1117626
              },
              "travel_mode": "DRIVING"
            }
          ],
          "traffic_speed_entry": [],
          "via_waypoint": []
        }
      ],
      "overview_polyline": {
        "points": "egxeIxk{KKHCL@TJr@xAk@J|@"
      },
      "summary": "Ascroft St i Harrison St",
      "warnings": [],
      "waypoint_order": []
    }
  ],
  "status": "OK"
};
for(var jsonvalue in json.routes){
var legs = json.routes[jsonvalue].legs;
    if(legs.length){
        for(var legvalue in legs){
        $("ul").append("<li>Distance : " + legs[legvalue].distance.text + " -- Duration : " +legs[legvalue].duration.text + " </li>")
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hi, Please have a look at my edit, this is what data bringsme back which has a weird formatting, but it should be json? therefore your code gives me no output :(

Comment: how come I get the output twice?

Comment: You are getting response twice?

Comment: No I don't but in the response it is shown several times
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZYaLY.jpg

Comment: You are using Chrome Browser and it display inline response. It will display full data when you expand it. That output is not twice. Don't worry everything is fine

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have an Object {} (and not just a string of text) you should be able to do

```
console.log(Object.routes)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think in success promise you aren't getting proper data format how you are expecting put a debug point on console.log in success promise and check the structure of the object and select the routes.

```
`success: function(data) { 
        console.log(data.routes);
 }`
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get a formatted stripped-down output with:

```
var formatted = JSON.stringify(data, 
    function(key, value) {
        // remove geocoded_waypoints
        if (key == "geocoded_waypoints") return;
        // remove other branches...
    return value;},
    2);
```

... or just only return the few keys you need.

Source: [W3C](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

Answer (score -2):

just parse your response:

```
var res=JSON.parse(response);
```

Comment: `dataType: 'json'` in the ajax settings means jQuery will parse it automatically, if the response is populated. Your code will try to parse an object, which is nonsensical and won't work.